# What happens after a process is forked?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, fork, x86-64

Say a process is forked from another process. In other words, we replicate a process through the fork function call. Now since forking is a copy-on-write mechanism, what happens is that whenever the forked process or the original process write to a page, they get a new physical page to write. So what I've understood, things go like this when both forked and original processes are executing.

--> when forking, all pages of original and forked process are given read only access, so that the kernel get to know which page is written. When that happens, the kernel maps a new physical page to the writing process, writes the previous content to it, and then gives the write access to that page. Now what I am not clear about is if both fork and original process write to the same page, will one of them will still hold the original physical page (prior to forking that is) or both will get new physical pages. Secondly, is my assumption correct that all pages in forked and original process are given read only access at time of forking?

--> Now since each page fault will trigger an interrupt, that means each write to original or forked process will slow down execution. Say if we know about the application, and we know that alot of contiguous memory pages will be written, wouldn't it be better to give write permission to multiple pages ( a group of pages lets say ) when one of the page in the group is written to. That would reduce the number of interrupts due to page fault handling. Isn't it? Sure, we may sometimes make a copy unnecessarily in this case, but I think an interrupt has much more overhead than writing 512 variables of type *long* (4096 bytes of a page). Is my understanding correct or am I missing something?

Comment: *What are your opinions ?* is not a good question on SO.

Comment: Well actually I'm asking if I'm understanding things correctly. I've edited the question accordingly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, one of the processes will be seen as writing to the page first. Even if you hae multiple cores, I believe the page fault will be handled serially. In that case, the first one to be caught will de-couple the pages of the two processes, so by the time the second writes to it, there won't be a fault, because it'll now have a writable page of its own.

I believe when that's done, the existing page is kept by one process (and set back to read/write), and one new copy is made for the other process.

I think your third point revolves around one simple point: "Say if we know about the application...". That's the problem right there: the OS does *not* know about the application. Essentially the only thing it "knows" will be indirect, through observation by the kernel coders. They will undoubtedly observe that `fork` is normally followed by `exec`, so that's the case for which they will undoubtedly optimize. Yes, that's not always the case, and you're obviously concerned about the other cases -- all I'm saying here is that they're sufficiently unusual that I'd guess little effort is expended on them.

I'm not quite sure I follow the logic or math about 512 longs in a 4096 byte page -- the *first* time a page is written, it gets duplicated and decoupled between the processes. From that point onward, further writes to either process' copy of that page will not cause any further page faults (at least related to the copy on write -- of course if a process sites idle a long time that data might be paged out to the page file, or something on that order, but it's irrelevant here).

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the initial cost, I know they get decoupled after!

Answer (score 1):

Fork semantically makes a copy of a process. Copy-on-write is an optimization which makes it much faster. Optimizations often have some hidden trade-off. Some cases are made faster, but others suffer. There is a cost to copy-on-write, but we hope that there will usually be a saving, because most of the copied pages will not in fact be written to by the child. In the ideal case,  the child performs an immediate exec.

So we suffer the page fault exceptions for a small number of pages, which is cheaper than copying all the pages upfront.

Most "lazy evaluation" type optimizations are of this nature.

A lazy list of a million items is more expensive to fully instantiate than a regular list of a million items. But if the consumer of the list only accesses the first 100 items, the lazy list wins.

Comment: I am asking about the case when fork is not used with exec. In other words I'm asking about the case where fork process is used as a replica of the original process.

Comment: Prior to exec taking place, the process is a already a replica. fork is just a library function that happens to be called in that replica.

Comment: Suppose a process does not fork, but runs some function, like servicing a client. Chances are that process will not mutate any large fraction of the copied address space it received from the parent. For one thing, there are all those code segments: executable, shared libs. All kinds of read-only data. Data that won't even be read by the child, never mind written. Code that will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the *initial cost* would be very high if fork() wouldn't use COW. If you look at typical `top` display, the ratio RSS/VSIZE is very small(e.g. 2MB/ 56MB for a typical vi session).

Cloning a process without COW would cause a tremendous amount of memory pressure, which would actually cause other processes to lose their attached pages (which will have to be moved to secondary storage, and maybe later restored). And that paging would actually cause 1-2 disk I/O's per page (the *swap out* is only needed if the page is new or dirty, the *swap in* will only be needed if the page is ever again referenced by the other process)

Another point is *granularity*: back in the days, when MMU's did not exist, whole processes had to be swapped out to yield their memory, causing the system to actually freeze for a second or so. Page-faulting on a per-page basis causes more traps, but these are spread out nicely, allowing the processes to actually *compete for physical ram*. 
Without prior knowledge, it's hard to beat an LRU scheme.